# Why Do Files Need "Prepared" When Finding References in VS2005

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, reference

Every time I try to find references to a method in a C# (ASP.NET) application I am developing, a screen always displays saying, "Preparing files for project 'MyProjectName.'

Visual Studio then appears to "index" my entire project (with a message saying, "Preparing file 'filename' for refactoring.")  This process takes very long and is becoming extremely detrimental to me being able to work quickly (10 minutes every time I want to do it).  Not using the capability is not an option since I am cleaning up a lot of code.

Any suggestions?  I don't see any promising settings in the properties.  This does not happen on any other machine on which I use VS2005.

Comment: Are you using some kind of add-in for Visual Studio?

Comment: Can you describe the project? Like, how many files, roughly how many thousand lines of code, and so on? Also, is there anything unusual about your project? (For example, last time someone reported such an issue to me, they had split up every class into like a dozen partial classes, and had thousands of classes scattered all over the place; they were hitting a path in the IDE that wasn't written with that code topology in mind.)

Comment: @nobugz - I'm not using any add-ins.

Comment: @Eric - The project is one I inherited.  It's not exceptionally large, although there are a number of files in a bin directory that come with the project that are fairly big (DLL files).  Also has an images folder with quite a number of images.  The rest of the folders contain relatively few aspx + their code-behind files.  There are a number of folders (one for each "feature" of the website, basically).  But, no more than 12 total.  (I'm working on reducing those...for obvious reasons.)

Comment: Does this performance problem repro consistently on other people's machines, or just yours? And what would be *really* awesome to know is if it repros on VS2008 or VS2010. If you have a massive performance problem like this that consistently repros on 2010, it is much more likely to get attention from the performance team. If this conversation would be easier to have via email than Stack Overflow comments, you can email me from the Contact link on my blog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there was something wrong with my previous VS2005 installation.  I uninstalled and performed a reinstall and everything is working how I'd expect.  Marking this as the answer.